# Display product attribute only when product is in stock in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

I have set up a Woocommerce attribute for delivery time and am displaying it on the single product page with this:

```
//Single Product
function product_attribute_delivery(){
    global $product;

    $taxonomy = 'pa_delivery';
    $value = $product->get_attribute( $taxonomy );

    if ( $value ) {
    $label = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
    echo '<p>' . $label . ': ' . $value . '</p>';
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary',  'product_attribute_delivery', 25 );
```

Would it be possible to only display it when the product is in stock?

Comment: You could add an IF Rule into your function,
if($product->get_stock_quantity() > 0) execute what you're already doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using [`WC_Product` `is_in_stock()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_is_in_stock)  method:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'product_attribute_delivery', 25 );
function product_attribute_delivery(){
    global $product;

    $taxonomy = 'pa_delivery';
    $value = $product->get_attribute( $taxonomy );

    if ( $value && $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $label = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
        echo '<p>' . $label . ': ' . $value . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work